# Can't add TryParseNull extension method to int in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add an extension method to int called TryParseNull that takes a string as input and returns the converted integer if successful or null if the string is not a valid integer.

I followed the doubleMe example from this post: [using extension methods on int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656974/using-extension-methods-on-int)

My extension method is declared like this:

```
public static class IntExtensions {
    public static int? TryParseNull(this string s) {
        int dummy;
        int? value;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out dummy)) {
            value = dummy;
        }
        else {
            value = null;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it like this the compiler complains that it doesn't know what TryParseNull is. I tried both of the below.

```
int? myNum = int?.TryParseNull("1");
int? myNum = int.TryParseNull("1");
```

Edit: I think the problem is the parameter `this string s`, but I'm passing in a string so I'm not sure how to rectify that.

Edit 2: From the answers below I can see what the problem is, but is there a way to have the syntax `int.TryParseNull("1")`?

Comment: `"1".TryParseNull()`

Comment: You cannot add static methods to a type you do not control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods work on instances of their 'this' parameter, not on the types.

Instead of

```
int? myNum = int?.TryParseNull("1");
```

Try

```
int? myNum = "1".TryParseNull();
```

**Edit:** 
Incidentally, you can also call the method statically with the 'this' parameter as the first argument.

```
int? myNum = IntExtensions.TryParseNull("1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
int? myNum = "1".TryParseNull();
```

Your method is extending `string`, not `int?`. It does return `int?`

Answer (score 0):

`int` is a framework provided type and the extension method you added was not originally part of the `int` implementation, so you cannot call it using the Type directly, you would need to call it on the instance of `int` as others have pointed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, you're trying to add a static method to an existing class. See the below:
[Can I "add" static methods to existing class in the .NET API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570629/can-i-add-static-methods-to-existing-class-in-the-net-api)

Short answer is you can't, extension methods only work for instances.